# Как начать читать файл с начала заново?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать, в нижеуказанному коде, что бы обрабатывалась обе строки, и S и B (**S, B : String;**) ?

```
  if rg_Order.ItemIndex = 1 then
  Begin
    for j := 0 to rL.Count - 1 do
      rL.Exchange(j, RandomRange(0, rL.Count));

    While Not EOF(F_Src) Do
      ReadLN(F_Src, S);
    S := StringReplace(S, edt_Word.Text, rL.Strings[K], RF);
    WriteLn(F_Tgt, S);
    inc(K);
    if K = rL.Count then
      K := 0;
  End;

  if rg_Order.ItemIndex = 1 then
  Begin
    for j := 0 to rL.Count - 1 do
      rL.Exchange(j, RandomRange(0, rL.Count));

    While Not EOF(F_Src) Do
      ReadLN(F_Src, B);
    B := StringReplace(B, edit3.Text, rL.Strings[K], RF);
    WriteLn(F_Tgt, B);
    inc(K);
    if K = rL.Count then
      K := 0;
  End;
```

Comment: Уберите лишний код из вопроса, пожалуйста. Он мешает.

Comment: Почитайте [mcve]

Comment: Сделано. Теперь подскажите.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что такое "одновременно" в вашем понимании?

Comment: В коде, что указан выше, функция делает замену слова построчно. Но только с строки S. А с строки B нет.

Comment: @Татьяна я отформатировал ваш код. Как вы считаете, после `While Not EOF(F_Src) Do` у вас не должно быть `begin`?

Comment: Так тоже делала и тоже самое.

Comment: @Татьяна но вы хотя бы в целом понимаете, что ваш код на самом деле делает? В отладчике по строкам проходили?

Comment: Что Вам нужно сделать с Вашим файлом?

Comment: Из одинаковых кусков кода надо сделать процедуры. Это все упростит. Думаю автор вопроса немного ошибся в алгоритме. Меняется только  последняя строка, так как замена вне цикла. Можно делать замену сразу обоих строк в одном и том же цикле, то есть сначала S, потом B хотя может я алгоритм до конца не понял.

Comment: И еще рекомендация - получать значения из контролов, до начала цикла в какую-либо переменную и с ней работать. Если цикл небольшой, то ничего страшного, но если файл огромный, то при получении значения edit3.text идут вызовы API, хотя конечно, компилятор может и оптимизировать это, а может и нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как начать читать файл с начала заново?

Используйте оператор **Seek**. Он перемещает указатель на заданную позицию.

```
Seek(F_Src, 0)
```

Первый параметр - handle файла
Второй позиция. 
Аналогичным образом можно переместится на конец

```
Seek(F_Src, FileSizeOf(F_Src))
```

Или отмотать несколько байт назад

```
Seek(F_Src, FilePos(F_Src) - 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Подсказываю:

```
  if rg_Order.ItemIndex = 1 then
  Begin
    ..
    While Not EOF(F_Src) Do  // Вы читаете файл до конца
      ReadLN(F_Src, S);
    ..
  End;

  if rg_Order.ItemIndex = 1 then
  Begin
    ..
    While Not EOF(F_Src) Do  // Вы читаете файл до конца.. но он уже "кончился" выше
      ReadLN(F_Src, B);
    ..
  End;
```

Перед повторным чтением файла - начните читать его с начала (см. функцию `reset(..)`).

Так же очень странно, что вы *ТАК* читаете файл по строкам, а обрабатывайте только последнюю прочитанную строку. Вероятно вы забыли `begin`/`end` после `while..do`?

Comment: Подсказка малоинтересна, т.к. первый цикл выберет весь файл до конца и обработается только последняя строчка

Comment: @AntonShchyrov верно. Поэтому это и подсказка, что повторного чтения файла не происходит вовсе. Про begin/end я выше уже подсказывал и был отметен.

Comment: Ребята, пробую и вижу что мне не хватает опыта. Может покажете как будет выглядеть код в моем варианте. Ну не опытная я еще... Прошу вас:( ...

Comment: @Татьяна если вы хотите, чтобы за вас все сделали, то вероятно вам на биржу фриланса ...

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку :(.

Comment: @Татьяна беритесь за ум, разделяйте сложный код на небольшие куски и решайте проблемы одну за одной, а не "все и сразу". Используйте нормальное форматирование кода. Учитесь пользоваться отладчиком и проверяйте как выполняется ваша программа "по шагам".